# Reach the Maximum by Flooring It

Tags: mathematics

A nice easy puzzle for the math lovers out there.

We're all familiar with the $\max$ function: $$\max \left( {x,y} \right) \triangleq \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  x&{{\text{if }}x \geq y} \\ 
  y&{{\text{otherwise}}} 
\end{array}} \right.\,\,\,\forall\, x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$

Suppose we wish to implement this function using no conditional logic and only a basic set of operations:

- multiplication, division, addition, and subtraction
- real-valued numeric constants
- the floor function, $\left\lfloor \cdot \right\rfloor$, which yields the greatest integer $\leq$ its argument (e.g. $\left\lfloor -1.5 \right\rfloor = -2$)

### Question

**Can you realize the $\max$ function for all real inputs using *only* these basic operations?**

Comment: I understood everything you said except what do you mean 'realize the max function'

Comment: @CyanogenCX: I mean "Can you build the $\max$ function out of these more primitive functions?" The aim is to show how you can compute the maximum of $x$ and $y$ using only the set of operations listed.

Comment: Makes me wonder. is there a way to do this without the floor function?

Comment: @IvoBeckers: You'd be limited to constructing rational functions (i.e. ratios of polynomials). I'm all but positive it wouldn't be possible to realize something as exotic as $\max$. If you (or any reader) figures out a way to do it, post it as an answer and I'll award it a 200 rep bounty out of being singularly impressed. ;)

Comment: @COTO it's easy to show mathematically $\max(x,y)$ is not a rational function, so it is indeed impossible without the floor.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The graph of $f(x):=x\cdot(1+x^2)^{-1}$ looks like:

[image]

This function
satisfies
$$
\big\lfloor f(x)\big\rfloor =\begin{cases}0:&x\geq 0,\\-1:&x<0. \end{cases}
$$
Using this, we can check that the function
$$
x-\left\lfloor\frac{x-y}{1+(x-y)^2}\right\rfloor(y-x)= x-\big\lfloor f(x-y)\big\rfloor(y-x)
$$
takes the value $\max\{x,y\}$:

- if $x\geq y$, then $\big\lfloor f(x-y)\big\rfloor =0$, so $x-\big\lfloor f(x-y)\big\rfloor(y-x)=x-0\cdot(y-x) =x$,
- if $x<y$, then $\big\lfloor f(x-y)\big\rfloor =-1$, so $x-\big\lfloor f(x-y)\big\rfloor(y-x)=x-(-1)\cdot(y-x) =y$.

Comment: You got it. I used exactly the same $f\left( x\right)$ but your second step is simpler (I used $\left| x\right|$ as an intermediary).

Comment: Could you please explain the answer in a much simpler way? I can not understand this. Thank you.

Comment: LOL. I love it when people ( preferable with good mathematics background ) say "It is not hard to see..." Reminds me of the good old days at university. But *no*, for people with less mathematical background it is far less easy to see. It can't hurt to edit in one or two sentences... (But yes, I *do* see the solution.)

Comment: @BmyGuest [How those without 'good' mathematical intuition see it] 1 + 1 = 2...From here, it's not hard to see how we get the answer x - floor[frac{x-y}{1+(x-y)^2}] \* (y-x)= x - floor[ f(x-y)] \* (y-x)...

Comment: Sorry, I've acquired some bad habits through years of writing for other mathematicians. I added some more explanation.

Comment: @JulianRosen You still don't explain the reasoning behind finding/using f(x)=x\*(1+x^2)^(-1), and why you did x-Floor[f(x-y)](y-x) ...which seems to be the main factor in the solution...although maybe I'm just not as good in math anymore

Answer (score 7):

I came up with this:
$$
\frac{\big\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\big\rfloor\cdot x+\big\lfloor\frac{y}{x}\big\rfloor\cdot y}{\big\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\big\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{y}{x}\right\rfloor}
$$
If $x$ is higher, then $\big\lfloor\frac{y}{x}\big\rfloor = 0$ and the fraction above equals $x$, same if $y$ is higher.

If $x=y$, then $\big\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\big\rfloor =\big\lfloor\frac{y}{x}\big\rfloor = 1$, and the fraction equals $\frac{x + y}{2}$, which is $\frac{2x}{2} = x$ (because $x = y$).

Comment: Doesn't this fail if x or y are 0 because some of the fractions will be undefined?

Comment: It's a neat concept, but Beska is right: we run into division-by-zero problems in some instances.

Comment: True, I completely overlooked the division by zero problem that appears... back to the drawing board, I guess :)